Encountered lav_object_summary Error while running CFA
This is my code:
DATA <- read_excel("FINAL DATA.xlsx")
CFA1 <-'
          F1 =~ Q1 + Q2 + Q3 + Q4
          F2 =~ Q5 + Q6 + Q7 + Q8
          F3 =~ Q9 + Q10 + Q11 + Q12
          F4 =~ Q13 + Q14 + Q15 + Q16
          M =~ 1*F1 + 1*F2 + 1*F3 + 1*F4
          F1 ~~ F2
          F1 ~~ F3
          F1 ~~ F4
          F2 ~~ F3
          F2 ~~ F4
          F3 ~~ F4
          '
f1 <- sem(CFA1, data= PHD_FINAL_DATA, std.lv=TRUE, ordered=c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4",
                                                             "Q5","Q6","Q7","Q8",
                                                             "Q9","Q10","Q11","Q12",
                                                             "Q13","Q14","Q15","Q16"))
summary(f1, rsquare= TRUE, fit.measures=TRUE)

However, I'm getting this error code when I run the summary line:

Error in lav_object_summary(object = object, header = header,
fit.measures = fit.measures, : unused argument (std.nox = std.nox)


The reprex below works with the latest version of lavaan. Could you try it and see if it works for you? Otherwise, you might just need to update lavaan to the latest version.
library(lavaan)
packageVersion("lavaan")
#> [1] '0.6.18'
HS.model <- ' visual  =~ x1 + x2 + x3
              textual =~ x4 + x5 + x6
              speed   =~ x7 + x8 + x9 '
fit <- sem(HS.model, data = HolzingerSwineford1939)
out <- summary(fit, rsquare= TRUE, fit.measures = TRUE)

Created on 2024-06-09 with reprex v2.1.0
Updated answer
To resolve your error, please install the latest version of blavaan. The source of the issue is a bit complicated but you can refer to the GitHub issue opened on about this.
Edit: I have deleted the old answer since it is not relevant anymore.

Thank you very much rempsyc. I removed tidySEM and tidyverse and rerun the analysis, it worked! Thanks again.

Do not upvote this answer. The problem is not in tidySEM: https://github.com/yrosseel/lavaan/issues/359

Thanks @CasparvanLissa I've updated the answer to ask users to download the latest version of blavaan instead, which I've confirmed work locally.

Hello @CasparvanLissa I tried to uninstall lavaan and installed the latest version, as well as the blavaan, tried to rerun the analysis with tidySEM and Im again getting:  Error in lav_object_summary(object = object, header = header, fit.measures = fit.measures,  :
unused argument (std.nox = std.nox)

@R.M.L. did you read this comment? https://github.com/yrosseel/lavaan/issues/359#issuecomment-2158069802
